# Are the works of J.E. Littlewood in ballistics stored somewhere?

Tags: mathematics

I watched the movie 'The Man Who Knew Infinity' and read the biography of J.E. Littlewood in Wikipedia. He worked on Ballistics in WW1.

Were those works were stored somewhere? I have checked on the internet; but haven't found any.

Comment: A [short research on Scholar Google](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=ballistic+author%3ALittlewood&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) do show a few articles on ballistic written by a JE Littlewood. Here are a few of them: [Littlewood, 1924](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100014146);[Littlewood & Littlewood, 1938](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-43/1/324.short); [Littlewood, 1968](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612676),

Comment: Not of immediate relevance to the question, but Hardy had a very low opinion of this work, although he had a very high opinion of Littlewood: he wrote: “even Littlewood could not make ballistics respectable, and if he could not who can?” [Hardy 1967, A Mathematician's Apology, p. 140].

Answer (score 7):

Littlewood described his WW1 work in Adventures in Ballistics, 1915-1918 published by Mathematical Spectrum magazine in two parts in 1971-72. Unfortunately, they store only [first pages online](http://ms.appliedprobability.org/content.aspx?Group=home&Page=Back_Issues_4), so you'd have to get paper copies.

Littlewood's contemporaneous papers, Formulae for Direct Fire and Anti-Aircraft Trajectories and Range Tables were published by War Office in London, 1917, which would be hard to get, I imagine. But they are discussed in Barrow-Green's [“Anti-aircraft guns all day long”:Karl Pearson and computing for the Ministry of Munitions](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ysZKMe-FIn0J:smf4.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/21/pdf/smf_rhm_21_111-150.pdf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) in Revue d’histoire des mathématiques 21 (2015), p. 111–150, which is conveniently cached by Google, and apparently reprinted in Pearson Papers ([cited here](https://books.google.com/books?id=8By8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=Littlewood,+Adventures+in+ballistics,+1915-1918&source=bl&ots=hoJODPhe6P&sig=7TuBFTcRfYuGCzy3zFvzAQ7WzSw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPvb_0u_nQAhVJCiwKHWfMBzgQ6AEIIzAD#v=onepage&q=Littlewood%2C%20Adventures%20in%20ballistics%2C%201915-1918&f=false)), which might be easier to find.

Comment: Adventures in Ballistics is included in his book Mathematical Miscelanea, which is more easily available.

Comment: Aren't some of his works are military secret? I mean the British Govt. could keep some of them out of publication.

Comment: @Mockingbird360 If it was it was declassified long ago, as the publication of the Pearson Papers indicates. There are far more precise methods of ballistic computation now, using computers.

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=8By8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA95)  suggests the Pearson Papers are in the [Univ. Coll. London Archives](http://archives.ucl.ac.uk/DServe/dserve.exe?dsqIni=Dserve.ini&dsqApp=Archive&dsqCmd=Show.tcl&dsqDb=Catalog&dsqPos=10&dsqSearch=%28%28PersonKey=%27karl%27%29AND%28PersonKey=%27pearson%27%29%29), which has a link to some digital images, whose server is not responding at the present time apparently.